# Nested string to tuple python

Tags: python

my String looks like:

```
"('f', ('d', ('a', 'b')), 'g')"
```

I want to convert that to tuple. 
How can  do that... I will use that in drawing a dendogram

Edit:
additional explanation:
my code and output's (print's):

```
print type(myString)                     # <type 'str'>
print myString                           #('f',('d',('a','b')),'g')
myString = ast.literal_eval(myString)
print type(myString)                     #<type 'tuple'>
print myString                           #('f', ('d', ('a', 'b')), 'g')

for tuple in myString:                   #f
    print tuple                          #('d', ('a', 'b'))
                                         #g
```

Comment: That already is a tuple. What do you want to do?

Comment: maybe he means his string actually is `hisString = "('f', ('d', ('a', 'b')), 'g')"`

Comment: The edit still doesn't make clear what you want.  You asked for a tuple; you got a tuple.  As a guess, do you want the tuple flattened, i.e. `("f", "d", "a", "b", "g")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

This will not let some malicious scripts run from the string provided as with `eval`.

Comment: if I try that i get  ('d', ('a', 'b')) as one element

Comment: @user1702981 Be more specific. Show exactly the code you try and what it does the other way your want it. We will help.

Comment: @user1702981 So you iterate over your newly generated tuple, and print each element. First element is `'f'`, and when printed it's `f`. The second is tuple and it's printed as is. The third is the string and printed the same way as the first one.

Comment: @user1702981 If you want it printed as ` f d a b g `, then you should recurively process all the nested tuples. Ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your help...I just thought that it's not ok transformed to tuple's but now when I tried my code (drawing binary three) it works... thank you @ovgolovin for answer

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) - for example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "('f', ('d', ('a', 'b')), 'g')"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
('f', ('d', ('a', 'b')), 'g')
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for that function says:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

Comment: @kache - no, that's `eval`, and the ability to do that sort of thing is very dangerous, which is why you should use `ast.literal_eval` instead.